# Testing event handlers

Tags: javascript

I have an event handler that modifies some global variable based on the click action. How can I test it? For example:

```
function initEvent() {
  function enable() {
    var arr = Context.get('arr');
    arr.push('aaa');
  };
  function disable() {
    var arr = Context.get('arr');
    arr.push('bbb');
  };
  $('#content').on('click', '#element', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
      enable();
    } else {
      disable();
    }
  });
};
```

This is the function I am calling after the HTML has been rendered. It calls `enable()` and `disable()` functions based on the user action. I want to test these functions and check if they behave correctly. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

One simple test you can do to test `enable`, `disable` and the click handler is to create a function that checks the contents of `arr` in `Context`, and call it after each of the functions within the click handler that add something to `arr`.

The general way to test conditions in your code is with assertions which will throw an error if the condition you pass into them is false. You can use [console.assert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/assert) just for that:

```
$('#content').on('click', '#element', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    enable();
    // assert last element in `arr` is the enabled string 'aaa'
    console.assert(
      Context.get('arr')[Context.get('arr').length - 1] === 'aaa',
      'enable() works'
    );
  } else {
    disable();
    // assert last element in `arr` is the disabled string 'bbb'
    console.assert(
      Context.get('arr')[Context.get('arr').length - 1] === 'bbb',
      'disable() works'
    );
  }
});
```

If any of the tests run after you click your element, you know `initEvent` assigned the click handler and it works. Then, you just toggle the `checked` flag to test `enable()`/`disable()` as well.

If there are no errors in your browser console, the tests have passed. Otherwise, there will be an error in your console containing the message passed as the second argument to `console.assert`.

You could even make a helper function to simplify the testing a bit:

```
function assertLastElementInContextArr(elem, msg) {
  var arr = Context.get('arr');
  // assert last item in `arr` is equal to `elem`
  console.assert(arr[arr.length - 1] === elem, msg);
}

$('#content').on('click', '#element', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    enable();
    // assert last element in `arr` is the enabled string 'aaa'
    assertLastElementInContextArr('aaa', 'enable() works');
  } else {
    disable();
    // assert last element in `arr` is the disabled string 'bbb'
    assertLastElementInContextArr('bbb', 'disable() works');
  }
});
```

**EDIT** based on your comment

> But how do I mock the click event? I mean, I want to automatically test all those events, no I have to somehow trigger the click automatically. How do I do that?

If you want to programmatically invoke click events, you can use JS to trigger them in code. Since you're using jQuery, it already comes with a method [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to do just that.

All you need to do is:

```
$('#content').trigger('click')
```

And it will activate your click handler and run the assertions tests from above.

In fact, jQuery even comes with aliased handlers for specific events so you can just do:

```
$('#content').click();
```

To automate the testing, you can create a function that will trigger the clicks and set the `checked` state as well, to test both cases.

```
function test(checked) {
  var elem = $('#content');
  elem.prop('checked', checked);
  elem.click();
}
```

Important thing to be careful about is that these events will happen asynchronously so you must do something to manage a proper testing order if you're going to trigger multiple clicks. Otherwise you will set `checked` to `true`, trigger the `click` and then run the second test that will set `checked` to `false` **before** the click events even happen.

For demonstration purposes, here's one way to safely test multiple successive clicks by adding an event handler just for testing and removing it once you're done. One requirement for this to work is to attach the handler after all your other handlers have been attached, to make sure the test handler runs last. Additionally, you can run your assertions here as well to not pollute your code and keep the testing fully separated:

```
function test(checked, value, msg, done) {
  var elem = $('#content');
  elem.prop('checked', checked);

  // attach a test event handler and trigger the click
  elem.on('click', testClick);
  elem.click();

  // once the click is executed, 
  // remove the test handler,
  // run the assertions and then
  // call the callback to signal the test is done
  function testClick() {
    elem.off('click', runTest);
    assertLastElementInContextArr(value, msg);
    done();
  }
}

// run your code before the tests
initEvent();

// test enable(), then once that's done, test disable()
test(true, 'aaa', 'enable() works', function() {
  test(false, 'bbb', 'disable() works', function() {
    console.log('All tests finished');
  });
});
```

If you're going to be testing your entire app like this, you'd probably want to use a test framework like [QUnit](https://qunitjs.com/), [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/), [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/) which will handle all these async issues for you and give you a nice API to work with.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I mock the click event? I mean, I want to automatically test all those events, no I have to somehow trigger the click automatically. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You want to test your code. You should never test code with `console.log` or `alert`. These are great to debug something on the fly, but they are not test tools. These promote manual testing, where you need to manually run the code and see that pass, that's horrible time waste.

You should use [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html) in this case (you can use other testing frameworks, though Jasmine is super easy) to test your code. You can setup browser tests or headless tests, which is out of the scope of this question, there are tons of tutorials on the subject.

Now, in order to test this code, I assume that the `Context` has a static method `get` which returns an array which is on the `Context` IIFE scope. If the case is different feel free to fiddle around with the specs and make it serve your needs, or alternatively if you get stuck, update this question or ask another one on Stackoverflow.

I have setup Jasmine, with [jasmine-fixture](https://github.com/searls/jasmine-fixture) to test your code, the jQuery click event behavior. In this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/K4Fo4n?p=preview) you will find everything you need.

I am using the browser to test the code, so I need jasmine's html reporter.
The real tests are in script-spec.js, where I am using Jasmine's API, by describing a spec suite (with `describe`) and defining each spec with `it` method.

In `beforeEach` I prepare the code to run before each spec executes. Essentially here, I create a simple `div` with `#content` id and a child `input` element of type checkbox with `#element` id. I do this by using the

`setFixtures('<div id="content"><input type="checkbox" id="element" /></div>');`

Which is a method jasmine-fixture library provides.

Now I can test the code, wiring up the specs:

```
  it("Should return an array with 'aaa' element when #element is checked", function() {
    // Arrange
    initEvent();
    var checkbox = $("#content").find("#element");

    // Act
    checkbox.click();

    // Assert
    expect(Context.get('arr').length).toBe(1);
    expect(Context.get('arr')).toEqual(['aaa']);
  });
```

I run the `initEvent` method and get a reference of the checkbox element. In Act section I click the element manually, marking it as checked, which is the normal behavior. In Assert, I test the `Context.get('arr')` return value.

Again, link to plunk is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/K4Fo4n?p=preview).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `console.log(<some variable>)` or `alert(<some variable>)` at function calls. e.g.:

```
function initEvent() {
  function enable() {
    alert("enable called!");
    var arr = Context.get('arr');
    arr.push('aaa');
  };
  function disable() {
    alert("disable called!");
    var arr = Context.get('arr');
    arr.push('bbb');
  };
  $('#content').on('click', '#element', function () {
    alert("click occured!");
    if (this.checked) {
      enable();
    } else {
      disable();
    }
  });
};
```

Or use your browsers developer tools setting breakpoints at these spots.

Comment: This is not a test technique, this is called debugging. Use test frameworks to test your code. The debugger should be used rarely, almost never, given the tests cover low level functionality and business needs (these are different kind of tests).

Comment: @gdyrrahitis I know it's called debugging. However, in the given scenario, when one is checking the functionality of his click-event, any suggestion of a high-end framework would be exaggerated and not very useful.

Comment: Testing is always useful. If he comes back to this code after some time and need to refactor how should he do that? No tests to run to tell what is working or not.